# react-star-rating-component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a react app about movies where i am trying to rate each movie. The problem I am facing right now is that i can not rate each movie separately. When i rate one movie all the movies get the same rating. Any idea on how to make it work? How can i rate each item separately ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      rating: 0
    };
  }

  onStarClick(nextValue) {
    this.setState({rating: nextValue
    });
  }

  render() {
   const { rating } = this.state;

    return (                
      <div>

        <h2>Top 10 movies</h2>
        {movies.map(c => (
          <div>
            <p key={c.name}>
              {c.name}
            </p>
        <StarRatingComponent 
          name="rate1" 
          starCount={10}
          value={rating}
          onStarClick={this.onStarClick.bind(this)} 

        />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a movie to rating mapping individually and not as a single integer. Keep it as an array

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      rating: new Array(movies.length).fill(0)
    };
  }

  onStarClick(index, nextValue) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({rating: [
           ...prevState.rating.slice(0, index),
           nextValue,
           ...prevState.rating.slice(index + 1)
       ]
   }));
  }

  render() {
   const { rating } = this.state;

    return (                
      <div>

        <h2>Top 10 movies</h2>
        {movies.map((c, index) => (
          <div>
            <p key={c.name}>
              {c.name}
            </p>
        <StarRatingComponent 
          name="rate1" 
          starCount={10}
          value={rating[index]}
          onStarClick={this.onStarClick.bind(this, index)} 

        />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```